# Proper way to parallelize this Python structure

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm writing some code in Python and hope that I can speed it up by sharing it between different processes. I have the following program substructure in Python 3.5 on Linux:

```
class Foo(fromMother):

   def __init__(self, size):
      fromMother.__init__()
      self.data = self.__createData(size)
      self.properGuess = 0

   def __createData(self, size):
      """Returns some dict of n x m numpy arrays."""

   def doStuff(self, level):
      """Calculates CPU-heavy, fully serial operation.
        The proper guess is some sort of start value."""
      a, b = foo(level, self.properGuess)
      self.properGuess = a
      return b



if __name__ == "__main__":
   foo = Foo(someSize)
   array = []
   for i in range(manyValues):
       array.append(foo.doStuff(i))
```

This is very roughly what my code does and I would like to find a nice way to introduce some parallel structure to use multiple cores. doStuff() can not be parallelized and is some kind of optimization problem, hence the starting value. It is not essential that this is the absolutely latest value, the function still gets executed fairly well at step i with a starting point calculated at i - 10, so it's completely okay to update this value 'every now and then'. But it can't be left out, the value of step i+1 is close to i and I know that the problem is not globally but only locally convex. Staying that close has given me quite stable results.

Unfortunately, breaking up the inheritance structure would be quite annoying - it's possible but should be the last resort. I wanted to use Python's own multiprocessing library but I'm a little confused with the shared memory etc, since this is not simply sharing some sort of array but having it in an object and using methods on it. I have only done parallel programming on MATLAB and this just on a very basic level.

Could someone point me a way to this. I'm thinking about this for two days already and I'm not sure how to achieve this nicely without breaking and "uglyfying" my entire structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a process pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

if __name__ == "__main__":
   foo = Foo(someSize)
   p = Pool(5)
   results = p.map(foo.doStuff, range(manyValues))
```

But, you need to think about some things first, is your class sharable?, will it mutate?, etc...

Comment: What about shared memory? Wouldn't this probably corrupt Foo.data or Foo.properGuess?

Comment: @DanielBischof, yes, it could, depends on what you have to do, but basically, if you are gonna write in the class you should use some control structure. Also notice that when spamming processes your class is not really shared but copyed, you should then use a shared structure for this.

Comment: Foo.data is a read-only structure - but if several processes read data at the same time from it, won't that become a problem? And what about properGuess? Can I simply map the Shared Memory value from multiprocessing here? And what about the result array? What's the return type for your variable 'results'?

Comment: @DanielBischof, if its read there is no problem. you can map the shared memory without problem, the return type is a list with the results of applying the `foo.doStuff` to each element of the `range`, a number I guess?

Comment: Coming back to this - that actually worked better than expected, thanks! Next question, while monitoring the next `level` step I realized that the pool takes values quite randomly out of that interval. Is there a possibility to tell the pool to take the smallest non-used value? For example it started with 15, which is a little too far away. If it was something like 1,2,4,5,3,6,9,8,7,11, ... etc that would work great..

Comment: @DanielBischof, there is no way of controlling the oder execution unless you make it to wait one process to another in which case you will not have a truly parallel computation

Comment: Okay, understood. I think my task might not be parallelizable on that level then, maybe on a more top level. Thanks anyways, I'll mark your answer as right, since it was more or less what I was looking for.